# Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'td' in angular2

Tags: angular2-template

in my angular 2 application In ts file i have below click even,

```
ViewPages(Char: string): void {
    this.selectedPage = Char;
}
```

In html, i tried to bind select page in ngif

```
<td *ngIf="name[0] == {{selectedPage}}">{{name}}</td>
```

but it is throwing the ""Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'td'.

it will be grt help if someone help me regarding this

Comment: Try:  `ng-if="name[0] == {{selectedPage}}"`

Comment: seems try instead of '==' --> '==='

Answer (score 3):

You should use **ng-container** for this. It isn't added to resulting html.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="name[0] == {{selectedPage}}">
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

And make sure, that **CommonModule** is imported.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})
```

Comment: i have tried this, i have added commonmodule in app.module.js and added this code in html, now im getting below error, Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container, If '*ngIf' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component. do we need to add this commonmodule in component.html as well?

Comment: Well, definitely problem is with CommonModule import. Can you add your module info file here?

Comment: You need to add it to every module that use it.. Is your component declared in app.module or somewhere else? If this is the case, add an import state there also.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("         <tr *ngFor="let Data of Data">
                            <ng-container [ERROR ->]*ngIf="name[0] == {{selectedPage}}">
                                <td>{{nam"): ng:///app/Pages/Pages.component.html@108:42
Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If '*ngIf' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from importing Common module in app.module.ts, we must declare the custom components created. Look for the html file in the console error and declare the corresponding component in app.module.ts