# I'm able to display the data fetched from an API in the input field in Angular 8 with error in the console

Tags: angular, api

I'm using an reactive form where i'm fetching data from the api and displaying in the html in the input field but i'm getting some error in the console. Need help in solving.

Below is the HTML code

```
 <form [formGroup]="homeForm" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="continue(homeForm.value)">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" class="text">Officer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="oName" value={{this.home[0].oName}} readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" class="text">Officer ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="oIDNum" readonly>
                </div>
  div align="end">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Below is the ts file code

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

   import{Router} from '@angular/router';
   import { ApiService } from '../app.service';


   @Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
 })
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  home:any

  constructor(private route:Router,private apiService:ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data)=>{
    this.home = data;
    console.log(this.home);
    })

  }
 homeForm = new FormGroup({
   oName:new FormControl(''),
   oIDNum:new FormControl(''),
   })
 continue(value){
  console.log(value);
  this.route.navigate(['/form']);
  }
 }
```

This is the service file

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
 export class ApiService {

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
 public getData(){
  return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:3000/officer`);
 }
}
```

JSON file data I'm using is below

```
{
 "officer":[ {
"oName": "Example",
"oIDNum": "1"
}]
}
```

[image: error in console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the value in the html

```
   value={{this.home[0].oName}}
```

And in the TS file you need to write it like this...

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data)=>{
    this.home = data;

    this.homeForm = new FormGroup({
    oName:new FormControl(this.home[0].oName),
    oIDNum:new FormControl(this.home[0].oIDNum),
    })
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the subscription from the component and use [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the template.

Also I see some other issues:

- The property `oName` is actually contained in the `officer` array.
- You might have to enclose the interpolation expression in double quotes.
- Use safe navigation operator [`?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) to make sure the variables are defined before trying to access their properties.

Try the following

Controller

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  home$: any;
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.home$ = this.apiService.getData();
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="home$ | async as data">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="oName" value="{{ data?.officer[0]?.oName }}" readonly>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You need to import the `CommonModule` in the component's module. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436611/6513921

Comment: I did that. Now I'm not getting any error but my input box disappeared from the page

Comment: Please insert `{{ data | json }}` inside the `ng-container` and see if it gets rendered in the DOM.

Comment: it is not rendering anything in DOM

Comment: I am not exactly sure. I've modified the answer to use an intermediary variable instead of directly calling the function from the template. Please see if it works. You could also check the browser debug console to see if the HTTP request is successful.

Comment: The edited solution worked for me and I have missed a info posting, in the api service i was using localhost:3000/officer to fetch data so no need to include officer in the value field. value="{{data[0]?.oName}}"

Comment: I got one more problem, on clicking submit button to go to next page it is not taking the form values. I have a console statement added to the submit function to check it.

Comment: I don't see any event handlers for the `Submit` button in the question?

Comment: in html i have written (ngSubmit)="continue(homeForm.value)" 
and in ts file 
continue(value){
  console.log(value);
  this.route.navigate(['/form']);
  }

Comment: So mean the values are not printed in the `console.log(value)` statement?

Answer (score 0):

In html use

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="oName" value={{this.home.officer[0].oName}} readonly>
```

i.e. use `value={{this.home.officer[0].oName}`} instead of `value={{this.home.[0].oName}}` as `this.home` is not an array, it is an object, `this.home.office`r is array

Comment: Data is not displaying now and now it is throwing error, Can't eady property 'officer' of undefined' and also the error in the old screenshot

Comment: please use {{home?.[0].oName}}